# count words unique in array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a Array, with a series of words that it collects in another function. What I intend is to count and separate those words that are unique and in the event that it is repeated do not count them. I've come this far, but the code stays in the first for. The goal is to count unique words in the array.

```
let arrayTemp = [];
Array1.forEach((item) => {
    if(arrayTemp[0]){
        arrayTemp[0] = item.perfilRoot;
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < arrayTemp.length; i++){
        if(item.perfilRoot != arrayTemp[i]){
            arrayTemp.push(item.perfilRoot);
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: use the words to naively name keys to an object (no checking for dupes needed), then call Object.keys() on it to get a unique list. or use a Set...

Comment: @Souleste thanks, but its no is the problem

Comment: You don't describe your input structure, or intended output, but something like this might get you on your way: `const uniques = [...new Set(Array1.map (item => item.perfilRoot))]`  But please edit the question to show sample input and requested output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using a Set.

```js
array = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5];
unique = [...new Set(array)];
console.log (unique.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which is an object that lets you store **unique** values.

```js
const valuesYouWant = Array1.map(item => item.perfilRoot); // new array with values you want from Array1
const uniqueValues = [...new Set(valuesYouWant)]; // new array with unique values from array valuesYouWant

console.log(uniqueValues); // this will log your unique values
console.log(uniqueValues.length); // this will log the length of the new created array holding the unique values
```

Comment: Will `Set` remove the ones that are duplicated as well? the question asked *What I intend is to count and separate those words that are unique and **in the event that it is repeated do not count them**.*

Comment: So do you want to create a new array with all values of your initial array but be stored only once (a), or do you want to save in a new array all values but if it happens a value to be repeated, to be removed **totally** from your collected values(b)?

Comment: Or more clearly, do you only want to **only** keep the non repeated values? Or do you also care about the values that are repeated but you only need to have them once?

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `Set` and check `size`

```
unique = new Set(YourArray);

console.log(unique.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Sets:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]
console.log(new Set(arr).size)
```

or you can use object like maps to count uniques keys:

```
let arr = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'squirrel', 'hawk', 'what a good dog'];
let m = {};

// count uniques words in array
arr.forEach(word => m[word] = 1);

// prints uniques counters 
console.log('count:', Object.keys(m).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to count the unique words, `Set` will not work. The code below looks at the array and only if the word is only found once in `Array1` does it add it to `arrayTemp`

```js
let arrayTemp = [];
Array1.map(a=>a.perfilRoot).forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index +1 < Array1.length && Array1.slice(index +1).indexOf(item) === -1) arrayTemp.push(item);
});
console.log(arrayTemp);
console.log('number of unique words', arrayTemp.length);
```